# Can't communicate electronjs-angularjs using IPC

Tags: javascript, angularjs, electron, webkit, desktop-application

I'm starting with electronjs desktop-apps so i decided to use angularjs for the views.

Now, when i try to use eletron ipc to communicate betweet these two i get **Cannot read property 'send' of undefined**.

This is what i've done so far:

#### main.js -- electronjs

```
var ipc = require('ipc');
ipc.send('asynchronous-message', 'ping');
```

#### app.controller.js -- angularjs

```
const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;
console.log(ipcRenderer.sendSync('synchronous-message', 'ping')); // prints "pong"

ipcRenderer.on('asynchronous-reply', function(event, arg) {
    console.log(arg); // prints "pong"
});
ipcRenderer.send('asynchronous-message', 'ping');
```

I'm obviously doing something wrong, can anyone give me a hand?

Comment: [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined) is a primitive and as such has no properties. That is why it does not have a `send` property. Code should avoid accessing properties of variables when they have no assigned value.

Comment: I know. What i need is someone to guide me in how to establish communication between electron and angularjs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Got it!!!**

When creating BrowserWindow in **main.js** set nodeIntegration true

```
win = new BrowserWindow({
show: false,
webPreferences: {
    nodeIntegration: true
  }
});
```

This allows angularjs to use require(), so in **app.controller.js** i just did

```
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron')
  // In renderer process (web page).
  console.log(ipcRenderer.sendSync('synchronous-message', 'ping')) // prints "pong"

  ipcRenderer.on('asynchronous-reply', (event, arg) => {
    console.log(arg) // prints "pong"
  })
  ipcRenderer.send('asynchronous-message', 'ping')
}
```

As result it prints in console: 
pong
pong